# Using ddply instead of for

Tags: r, for-loop, plyr

I'm quite new to plyr package (and R in general)
I have following code

```
# I have some dataframe df 
# columns: 
#     -somefactor: factor
#     -value:      numeric

f<-levels(df$somefactor)
k<-length(f)
m<-mat.or.vec(k,k)
for(i in 1:k) {
  for (j in 1:k)
    m[i,j]=cor(df[somefactor==f[i],]$value,df[somefactor==f[j],]$value)
}
```

How could I simplify this code using ddply function (or something similar, just to remove those ugly for cycles

Thank a lot!

Fida

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like that :

```
cor(as.data.frame(split(df$value, df$somefactor)))
```